# When using dart command it just returns a dot as response

Tags: dart

In macOS Monterey v12.1, when I use dart command, it shows me a "."

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.9.0-1.0.pre.491, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale en-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✗] Cannot determine if IntelliJ is installed
    ✗ Directory listing failed
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[!] HTTP Host Availability
    ✗ HTTP host https://maven.google.com/ is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Operation timed out

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

[image]

Comment: What does: `which dart` return? (not sure that command works on Mac OSX but I guess it behaves similar to Linux)

Comment: Maybe also add that you have made the same question on the Dart SDK issue tracker: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/48208 . Just so people are not trying to do stuff you have already tried or being suggested.

Comment: @julemand101 /Users/s.s./development/flutter/bin/dart

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -R $(echo $USER):staff $(echo ~)
```

Something about permission, this command fixed my problem.

Comment: This command solved the dart analyzer terminated problem that I was having in VS Code since past week or so. No autocomplete or intellisense was working after i updated flutter. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Kinda found some interesting solution when i saw there is a env specified/highlighted in the vscode dart extension page.
After i added the env FLUTTER_ROOT which is the flutter sdk path, the error no longer exists.

Hope this help