# Dart analysis server terminated VS Code

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

2 days ago, I upgraded Flutter and since then, dart has basically stopped working in VS Code. By that, I mean that VS Code does not identify any error in Flutter app. No Coding error and no package error. Nothing happens if I press `Cmd Enter` Whenever I start VS Code, I get the same errors and these errors are: 1: `The Dart Analysis Server server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted.`

2: `Dart DevTools exited with code 255. Would you like to try reactivating DevTools?`

3: `The Dart Analyzer has terminated.`

So far, I have tried numerous solutions which include downgrading flutter version to 2.8.1, 2.5.0. I have also tried running the command `flutter pub global activate devtools -v 2.8.0`. I have even tried uninstalling vs code and installing it from scratch.

Is there any solution to this mess? Is there anyone else with this same issue recently?
Thanks!!!

Flutter Version: 2.10.0
macOS Version: 11.4(Big Sur)

P.S. Seems to be a problem in VS Code only since it seems to be working fine in IntelliJ. Still, no solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, after searching long and hard for this. I cam across a similar question here on StackOverflow and the answer provided by the person who posted that question, worked for me too. I ran the following command:

`sudo chown -R $(echo $USER):staff $(echo ~)`

Whenever, I would try to run the command that started with 'dart', I would get a full stop(`.`). And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70844367/when-using-dart-command-it-just-returns-a-dot-as-response) question was exactly about that.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix the problem until ran this command `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

ok for me, i just uninstalled my flutter and dart extension on vs code and then reinstalled them